# How do you NOT get an index entry in the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, imakeidx

My problem is that I don't want the automated index entry to appear in the TOC but would rather add one manually. But no matter what I try, the automated entry always appears.

I have tried combinations of the following:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\makeindex[columns=3,  intoc=false]
\makeindex[intoc=false]

\printindex
```

Another problem I seem to be having is that the key-values with `imakeidx-makeindex` don't seem to do anything at all, and `\indexsetup` in preamble returns an error. I have used repeated builds so it is not smoke and mirrors by the TOC builder.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: don't use `maikeidx` and `imakeidx` at the same time. pick only `imakeidx`

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. The option `intoc=false` is set by default in the `imakeidx` package and there is no `ToC` entry using this small document.

Using `intoc=true` works too if the `ToC` should be made.

However, `makeidx` and `imakeidx` shouldn't be loaded together. Use the more up-to-date `imakeidx`

The package `tocbibind` shouldn't be loaded as well as it does not work together with `imakeidx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}


\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3,title={Index of more or less famous \TeX\ folks},intoc=false]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\vskip\baselineskip

A lot of people spend their time on \url{www.tex.stackexchange.com}, to boldly \TeX\ where others don't dare ;-)


\index{egreg}
\index{Paulo}
\index{David}
\index{Werner}
\index{Johannes}
\index{Joseph}
\index{Harish}
\index{Clemens}
\index{Heiko}
\index{Will}
\index{Bruno}
\index{Gonzalo}
\index{Mico}
\index{Ulrike}
\index{barbara}
\index{cfr}
\index{BlackForester}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]